# Restoring a Google Doc from Trash using Zend GData

Tags: php, gdata-api, google-docs-api, zend-gdata

I am creating a filemanger that uses Google Docs for storage, but I am having difficulty working out how to restore a file that has been sent to the trash.  I can send to trash by using this code:

```
$resourceId = "file:12345";
$link = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/";
$file = $docs->getDocumentListEntry($link.$resourceId);
$file->delete();
```

I can then view all trashed documents using:

```
$docs = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($client);
$docs->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);
$feed = $docs->getDocumentListFeed($link."-/trashed");

foreach($feed->entries as $entry) {
  ...
}
```

My question is how can I then restore one of these files back to location it was before it was deleted as you can in Google Docs proper?

Comment: Ok, so worked out you need to edit the metadata to restore from the Trash.  By editing the following:
`<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005/labels" term="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005/labels#trash" label="trashed"/>`

to:


`<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005/labels" term="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005/labels#trash" label=""/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I worked out how to restore trashed files in my Google Docs App.  Code is as follows:

```
$service = Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($gUser, $gPass, $service);
$client->setHeaders('If-Match: *');
$gdocs = new Zend_GData_Docs($client);
$gdocs->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);

$slug = array('If-Match'=>'*'); 

$link = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/".$resourceId;
$entry = $gdocs->getDocumentListEntry($link);
$xml = $entry->getXML();
$feed = str_replace('label="trashed"', 'label=""',$xml);

$entryResult = $gdocs->updateEntry($feed, $entry->getEditLink()->href,null,$slug);
```

This will also work for unstarring a document and with other category elements. So for example:

Replace:

```
$feed = str_replace('label="trashed"', 'label=""',$xml);
```

With:

```
$feed = str_replace('label="starred"', 'label=""',$xml);
```